# ssh-agent is not starting in Git-Bash Windows

Tags: windows, git-bash

All of a sudden, my Git-Bash is not starting up the ssh-agent and it hangs in there. So trouble this further, I have manually executed the below command and it hangs in there.

> $ eval `ssh-agent -s`

And in the Windows Machine, I could see the process is alive

```
 > Get-Process *bash, *ssh-add, *ssh-agent

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
    229      20     8484      12980       0.17   2516   1 bash
    149      18     2884       8544       0.06  37152   1 git-bash
    231      19     6628       9416     133.69   9844   1 ssh-agent


> Get-Service ssh-agent | Select StartType

StartType
---------
   Manual
```

**Additional Note:**

- If I type `ssh-agent` in command-prompt or in powershell it seems to execute fine. Only in Git Bash it seems to not work and this happened very recently.

Trying to understand, why ssh-agent is not getting started and hangs in ?

Comment: Note that Git itself is not responsible for ssh (nor vice versa). The way ssh-agent works with standard Unix shells is a bit klunky. macOS gets around this by starting ssh for you when you log in to the mac, but that requires that someone have thought of this when writing the OS. (Linux can be made to do this too, but for whatever reason it has not become standard in standard Linux distributions.) (I avoid Windows and have no advice on setting up ssh-agent there.)

Comment: @torek: actual git is separate from ssh, which is almost always supplied on Unix systems, but until recently Windows didn't include this and other things git needs so https://git-scm.com/download/win packages git together with a Unix-like environment based on mingw64, including things like bash cmp diff and among them its own copies of OpenSSH and OpenSSL. Maryo: do you want the ssh-agent that is now supplied with Windows 10 up (which is the one that is a 'service' in Windows) or the win-git one?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, I would prefer the windows provided one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove/rename `agent.env` file located in `~/.ssh` directory.

If you adding keys during Git-Bash startup, new file will be created automatically when Git Bash is started again (startup scripts are executed).